# Wrong IP address returned for pfSense host name on a router with multiple LANs when using DNS Forwarder/Resolver

Tags: domain-name-system, pfsense, multi-homed

*Question moved from StackOverflow:*

Running pfSense 2.4.4 (first saw the problem in 2.0.3) using DNS Forwarder or DNS Resolver for Split-DNS with multiple LANs. LAN1 is 10.10.10.0/24 and LAN2 is 192.168.69.0/24. pfSense router is .1 on both interfaces and DNS Forwarder/Resolver is configured for LAN2 and localhost, only.

When router is DNS queried for it's own IP address (pfsense.router.home), 10.10.10.1 is returned instead of 192.168.69.1.

How can I get it to return the IP address from LAN2?

Answer (score 0):

It is 10 years since I first encountered this yet it is still very difficult to find a solution in Google. [The problem is described here](https://redmine.pfsense.org/issues/7680) and these are my solutions.

In 2.0.3, with DNS Forwarder, I solved this by literally changing the order of the interfaces so the first LAN interface IP was the one I wanted to resolve for the pfSense hostname (LAN2 in my example).

In 2.4.4, using DNS Resolver, this can be done by

1. Disabling automatically added host entries
   `Services/DNS Resolver/Advanced Settings/Disable Auto-added Host Entries`
2. Manually adding a Host Name Override for the router
   `Services/DNS Resolver/General Settings/Host Overrides`